# Optimizar función carga json con utf8_decode

Tags: php

tengo la siguiente función, pero el tiempo de ejecución es muy largo, porque el JSON es muy grande, la cosa es que el json no tiene siempre el mismo formato, por eso es recursíva, hasta que encuentre el ultimo elemento. Pero necesito mejorar el rendimiento de la función ya que tarda demasiado y ralentiza la carga.

```
function jsonDecode($objeto) {
    return utf8Decode(json_decode($objeto,true));
}

function utf8Decode($objeto) {
    $salida = false;
    if(is_array($objeto)) {
        $salida = array();
        foreach($objeto as $indice=>$valor) $salida[utf8_decode($indice)] = utf8Decode($valor);
    }
    else $salida = utf8_decode($objeto);
    return $salida;
}
```

gracias y un saludo

Comment: ¿También hace falta hacer el `utf8_decode` a los índices?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo único a lo que quisieras hacer `ut8_decode` fuese a los valores, podrías usar una función como [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) para atravesar los nodos hoja de la siguiente manera:

```
function utf8Decode(&$item, $key) {
    $item = utf8_decode($item);
}

function jsonDecode($objeto) {
    $aux = json_decode($objeto, true);
    array_walk_recursive($aux, 'utf8Decode');
    return $aux;
}
```

Pero parece que también quieres aplicar el `utf8_decode` a los índices y entonces éste método no te serviría (sólo permite modificar el valor de los nodos, no de los índices). Y esto hará que todo se complique bastante.

Entonces me centraría en la recursividad. Las funciones recursivas pueden ser muy bonitas, elegantes y fáciles de leer (a veces), pero vienen con algunos problemas: en general son más lentas y consumen más recursos (hay que preparar la llamada a la función, reservar memoria, copiar variables y parámetros...)

Así que para optimizar el código, te sugeriría que eliminases la recursión y utilices bucles en su lugar... aunque eso es muy fácil de decir pero no tan sencillo de hacer en algunos casos (especialmente si la recursividad no es de cola, que no es en tu caso).

En esta [respuesta de mvds en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3251931/3695983), puedes encontrar una versión iterativa del algoritmo que atraviesa un array multidimensional. Modificándola un poco puedes crear un algoritmo que hace esto:

1. Atraviesa los diferentes niveles del array de manera iterativa
2. Por cada elemento hoja añade un nodo al array de salida (los subniveles se separan con un carácter que no debe existir en el índice, yo use `|`)
3. Cuando se haya generado el array de salida, atraviesalo

   1. Si el índice contiene el caracter separador

      1. Separa el índice y añade el valor al subnivel correspondiente
      2. Elimina el índice del array usando `unset`

El resultado quedaría así:

```
function jsonDecode($objeto) {

    $objeto = json_decode($objeto, true);
    $salida = array();

    // atravesamos el objeto añadiendo todos los valores a la salida
    while ( count($objeto) > 0 )
    {
        $defer = array();
        foreach ( $objeto as $indice => $valor )
        {   
            if ( is_array($valor) )
            {
                $salida[utf8_decode($indice)] = array();
                foreach ( $valor as $kk => $vv ) {
                    $defer["$indice|$kk"] = $vv;
                }
            } else {
                $salida[utf8_decode($indice)] = utf8_decode($valor);
            }       
        }   
        $objeto = $defer;
    }

    // atravesamos la salida para añadir los subniveles
    foreach($salida as $indice => $valor) {
        if (strrpos($indice, "|")) {
            eval("\$aux = &\$salida[" . implode("][", explode("|", $indice)) . "];");
            $aux = $valor;
            unset($salida[$indice]);
        }
    }

    return $salida;
}
```

Que es una versión iterativa de tu función recursiva. PERO (siempre hay un pero), esta solución presenta varios problemas:

- Usa el método `eval`, que no es recomendado.
- Los resultados que he obtenido son más lentos que la versión recursiva (pero no sé cómo afectaría un JSON mucho más grande y anidado que el que yo he utilizado de prueba)

Podrías probar con este algoritmo como base, porque atraviesa el array de manera iterativa, y crear algo más eficiente de lo que yo he hecho.